# Python - Better way to compare 2 csv files and add 2 new columns if condition met?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Goal:

1. Compare 2 CSV files (Pandas DataFrames)
2. If `user_id` value matches in rows, add values of `country` and `year_of_birth` columns from one DataFrame into corresponding row/columns in second DataFrame
3. Create new CSV file from resulting "full" (updated) DataFrame

The below code works, but it takes a LONG time when the CSV files are large. I have to imagine there is a better way to do this, I just haven't been able to figure it out.

Current code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Imports
import pandas as pd

# Variables / Arrays
import_optin_file_name = "full_data.csv"
import_extravars_file_name = "id-country-dob.csv"
export_file_name = "new_list.csv"

# Create DataFrames from 2 imported CSV files
optin_infile = pd.read_csv(import_optin_file_name)
extravars_infile = pd.read_csv(import_extravars_file_name)

# Create/Insert new columns to "optin_infile" dataframe (country,year_of_birth) with initial value of NULL
optin_infile.insert(loc=7, column='country', value='NULL')
optin_infile.insert(loc=8, column='year_of_birth', value='NULL')

# Iterate through rows, compare user_id - if match, add value to country, year_of_birth columns
for ev_index, ev_row in extravars_infile.iterrows():
    for optin_index, optin_row in optin_infile.iterrows():
        if ev_row['user_id'] == optin_row['user_id']:
            optin_infile.loc[optin_index, 'country'] = ev_row['country']
            optin_infile.loc[optin_index, 'year_of_birth'] = ev_row['year_of_birth']

# export to new CSV file
optin_infile.to_csv(export_file_name, header=True, index=False)
```

Any suggestions/examples of how to get this to work better with large csv files are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

**UPDATE 02/28/2022**

My comment response to one of the answers did not come out clear, so I am posting the update here. I used `Raymond Kwok`'s answer, and got it to work much faster. I do have one minor data issue. During the merge, it seems that the `year_of_birth` column changes type? Meaning, if the value is originally `1987`, after the merge, in the new DataFrame, it ends up being `1987.0`.

My updated code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Imports
import pandas as pd

# Variables / Arrays
import_optin_file_name = "full_data.csv"
import_extravars_file_name = "id-country-dob.csv"
export_file_name = "new_list.csv"

# Create DataFrames from 2 imported CSV files
optin_infile = pd.read_csv(import_optin_file_name)
extravars_infile = pd.read_csv(import_extravars_file_name)

# Merge extravars into optin when user_id matches
outcome = optin_infile.merge(
    extravars_infile[['user_id', 'country', 'year_of_birth']], 
    on='user_id', how='left'
)

# Replace blank (no) values with NULL
outcome.fillna('NULL', inplace=True)

# Export to new CSV file
outcome.to_csv(export_file_name, index=False)
```

To try and solve the `year_of_birth` data type issue, i added this line before the merge - `extravars_infile['year_of_birth'] = extravars_infile['year_of_birth'].astype('object')` - This works fine for small CSV files, but not for larger ones.

Any thoughts? Thanks for the help!

** ***UPDATE - data type issue fix*** **
`Raymond Kwok` to the rescue again. Added the following line to this section:

```
# Replace blank (no) values with NULL
outcome['year_of_birth'] = outcome['year_of_birth'].fillna(-1).astype(int).astype(str).replace('-1', ' NULL')
outcome.fillna('NULL', inplace=True)
```

this solved the `1987.0` issue. Thanks so much.

Next issue is that the resulting CSV file is ~2 million rows longer than the original file - the row count should match, which means it is duplicating rows. I am looking into this, I am suspecting that it is not handling double entries of the same `user_id` in both files properly. This was one of the reasons I wanted to go row by row and check (original code), but alas, that doesn't scale too well with large files. Any further help is appreciated, and I will post here if I end up confirming the suspected problem and figure out a way to work-around or clean up the result.

Thanks!!

** ***UPDATE - duplicated lines in merge (kind-of) fix*** **
As suspected, the issue happened because both files had duplicate rows with the same `user_id`. This is expected, but with my original row-by-row comparison, I didn't have to worry about it, because it would never add rows anyways. With `merge`, however, it must read it differently, so it produced multiple duplicate rows. I solved this by "cleaning" one of the files (labeled `import_extravars_file_name` in the code) beforehand, essentially grouping and reducing it to one row per multiple `user_id` values.

The reason I say "kind of" a fix is because I don't know if there is a better way to do this, within the confines of the merge statement itself.

But ultimately, I do have a solution that works.

Thanks all for the help, and especially `Raymond Kwok`, who supplied the merge code for me to start down the path to success.

Thanks!!

Comment: This sounds like a join. Use the variosu `join`/`merge` capabilities built in to pandas. Even if you *were* going to hand-code this, you should use an *index*, i.e. a `dict` to group first, otherwise you are brute-forcing it and it's highly inefficient

Comment: I tried various join and merge statements, but none worked with a search for the user_id - as in, take the user_id from each row in one csv, compare it to each row in the 2nd csv, and if there are matches, add the value of country and year. If you have any code examples that would do this, i can try again. Thanks!

Comment: That doesn't make any sense, that is *precisely* what join/merge does. You **must** provide a [mcve]

Comment: I don't have any examples using join/ merge, because I couldn't get anything at all to work using those. I provided an example in my original post of what actually works, asking for examples of how it could work faster for larger files.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I provided an entire working script. The post is requesting any suggestions/examples of how to get this to work better/quicker with large csv files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed `merge`, moreover, you need to make sure the `'user_id'` columns from both dataframes **have the same data type** for `merge` to be able to identify matches. For example, `123` as integer ***won't*** match with `'123'` as string.

```
outcome = optin_infile.merge(
    extravars_infile[['user_id', 'country', 'year_of_birth']], 
    on='user_id', how='left'
)

outcome.to_csv(export_file_name, index=False)
```

If you are wondering why your attempts on using `merge` didn't work, ***after making sure about the datatype***, then, share your code that involves the failed `merge`, and share minimum number of rows of each of your dataframes so that we can reproduce your failure attempt in our computer and investigate for the reason.

Comment: There isn't a data type issue that I have seen. If there were, than my `if` comparison line in my original post wouldn't work, and it works just fine. Are you saying that merge would work better for large files? Should it replace the `.loc` lines? Thanks!

Comment: I think you can time both approaches and see the difference :)

Comment: Okay this worked great, with one small issue. I tried posting it here in a comment, but it formatted badly, so I updated my original post. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Do this `print(outcome['year_of_birth'].isna().sum())` after the `merge` line and you should see a positive value which means there are `np.nan` in the `outcome` which will by default turn its datatype into `float` and that's why you see `.0`. One way out is `outcome['year_of_birth'] = outcome['year_of_birth'].fillna(-1).astype(int).astype(str).replace('-1', ' NULL')`

Comment: Looks like the merge is also duplicating lines as well with large files. Import file was ~900,000 lines, using merge, resulting file is ~2.9 million. These row counts should be the same, all I should be doing is adding 2 columns to the end of each row. This doesn't happen when the import file has 7 rows

Comment: `outcome['year_of_birth'] = outcome['year_of_birth'].fillna(-1).astype(int).astype(str).replace('-1', ' NULL')` worked great to fix the `.0` issue, thanks! Now I have to figure out why the out put merged file has over 2 million more rows than the original file. I am looking into this now, but any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have a particular user_id that exists 3 times in one df and 5 times in another, you will end up getting 15records for that id. `df['user_id'].value_counts().sort_values(ascending=False)` will give you some ideas